# using QtWebkit headless in Qt GUI app

Tags: pdf, qtwebkit

i need to use Qtwebkit functions in GUI application but i do not want to view the webkit in my GUI app.
the main function is to render HTML to pdf . 
i know i can do it with QtWebkit headless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QWebPage](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebpage.html) since it can work without displaying anything on the screen. Something like:

```
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName(fileName);

page->mainFrame->print(&printer);
```